# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for when 'choose file' is clicked:

```
$(':file').change(function () {

if(this.files.length == 1) {
    $('#selected_files').html("<h4>Attaching " + this.files.length + " file</h4>");
} else {
    $('#selected_files').html("<h4>Attaching " + this.files.length + " files</h4>");
}

$('#selected_files').append("<table class=\"altShaded\"><thead><tr><td></td><td>Filename</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead>");

for(x=0;x<=this.files.length;x++)
{
    var file = this.files[x], 
    name = file.name, 
    size = file.size, 
    type = file.type;
    $('#selected_files').append("<tr><td></td><td><b>" + name + "</b> ("+filesize(size)+") " + type + "<br>");
}


});
```

Fine, right? And all works well.  That's great, except that when jQuery appends the table rows, it seems to like to start a new table, and the top `<thead>` isnt attached the to rows (in Chrome).

Okay I thought, we'll just build a string and put it all in at once.

Thus:

```
$(':file').change(function () {

        if(this.files.length == 1) {
            var displayFiles = "<h4>Attaching " + this.files.length + " file</h4>";
        } else {
            var displayFiles = "<h4>Attaching " + this.files.length + " files</h4>";
        }


        var displayFiles = displayFiles + "<table class=\"altShaded\"><thead><tr><td></td><td>Filename</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead>";
        for(x=0;x<=this.files.length;x++)
        {
            var file = this.files[x], 
            name = file.name, 
            size = file.size, 
            type = file.type;
            displayFiles = displayFiles + "<tr><td>" + type + "</td><td><b>" + name + "</b></td><td>"+filesize(size)+"</td></tr>";
        }

        $('#selected_files').html(displayFiles);
    });
```

But now all of a sudden,  I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined **

Nothing has changed, except the code around it.  It is pointing to:

**name = file.name,**

Can you tell me what the problem is here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of error mean that your container variable `file`is not defined.

You should use `console.log` at different places to see what is defined and what is not (your files array, etc.)

Also :

```
for(x=0;x<=this.files.length;x++)
```

Will be undefined for the last `x` value, because the last element of an array is at `array.length - 1`and not `array.length`, that gives you an undefined value at the end of your loop, probably the source of your error. In your case, x goes to the value `this.files.length`
Also, always use var, otherwise your `x`will be a global variable, which can be another source of problems.

A correct loop should be :

```
for (var x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++)
```

Comment: That sorted it! I wasnt getting any output because at the end, it was undefined.  Therefore it never set the string to the Div.  Wheras the last one had the error, I just didnt see it beause it was outputting :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code with the problem,

```
for (var index = 0; index <= results.length; index++) {
//doSumthing
}
```

Working code ,

```
for (var index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
//doSumthing
}
```

The problem was with the `=` operator in `for` loop statement. It was checking for the element that does not exist(last element+1) in the array.

Try removing `=` from your loop statement, like this.

```
for(var x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++){}
```

It might work!

Answer (score 1):

I was having same error and it was happening because of a stupid mistake.
I removed on module from imports array and accidentally left comma on that line.....so there were two commas (,,) in imports: [] array....after removing one comma it solved the problem.